# Count number of years since last deduction

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table similar to below where the same account has its fiscal years (FY) and deductions for each year broken out in multiple rows. Accounts can range from 1 - 20+ years. How do I group to one unique row that shows the current year and how many years its been since the account had a deduction?

from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Started to utilize the CTE approach as I have in the past, but as before it started to get ugly and I know there has to be a simpler approach...

Comment: This is likely possible to achieve using Last_Value and RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED PRECEDING as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the current year is the most recent year, you would use aggregation:

```
select account, max(fy),
       sum(case when fy = max_fy then deductions end) as this_year_deduction,
       max(fy) - max(case when deduction < 0 then fy end) as years_since_deduction
from (select t.*, max(fy) over (partition by account) as max_fy
      from t
     ) t
group by account;
```

Note:  I assume the third column is the most recent deduction.  The query uses a window function to extract that.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. The only thing I had to change was the case when deduction > 0 to < 0 as it is evaluating against negatives.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used the methods below but I think it is close to what is needed. Corrections welcome. (Code not tested)

```
with nonZeroes as 
(
  select * from YourTable where deductions <> 0 
)  

select Account, 
           FY, 
           FY - LAST_VALUE(FY) OVER (PARTITION BY Account    
                      ORDER BY Year Desc   
                      RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS years_since_deductions  
        from nonZeroes
```